# PHPMailer: Hide body text from email address

Tags: php, phpmailer

I was wondering if it was possible to hide certain parts of the body message in PHPMailer depending on the email address. I have 2 email addresses that are being sent the message, and the second email address needs to only see parts of what the first email address is seeing. Is there a way to identify that I only want the first email address to see the content. For example:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->AddReplyTo($fromemail, "".$fromname."");
$mail->AddReplyTo("emailaddress1@abc.com", "Company ABC");
$mail->SetFrom($fromemail, "".$fromname."");
$mail->AddAddress("emailaddress1@abc.com", "Company ABC");//would see the whole email
$mail->AddAddress("partneraddress@somecompany.com", "Partner Company");//would only see 1st paragraph
$subject = "Email Subject";
$mail->AltBody = "To view this message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer";
$mail_body .= "
<html>
  <head>
   <title>Email Message</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>This would be a paragraph that both email addresses see</p>";
if ($mail->AddAddress == "emailaddress1@abc.com") {
$mail_body .= "<p>This would only be seen by the first address</p>";
   } 
$mail_body .= "</body>
</html>";
```

Comment: Why not just generate two separate emails? Anything else is going to be a client-side solution, so you'd be sending the "hidden" text to both recipients. Don't know about you, but "pretty please with sprinkles on top don't read this if you're user XYZ" won't work with me...

Comment: Marc, I certainly can generate 2 separate emails. I wanted to find out from others that use PHPMailer if using server side code could make it possible to show certain parts of the mail body to one email address and other parts to another. If your regards to your quote about pretty please, have not got a clue what you are talking about in regards to what won't for you??

Comment: PHP mailer's job is not to be aware of the contents of the email and what to send and what to not send. That's entirely up to you to determine. So if you want person X to not see something intended for person Y, then don't send that stuff to person X in the first place, e.g... send 2 separate emails.

Comment: Thanks Marc for explaining what was meant. I do already send separate emails and wanted to check with others if they had done it by using code to send 1 email to multiple people and have only certain information available to specific emails. This would be easier than having to go against DRY methodology. But I will do so seeing that it does not seem possible. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

This will not be possible without sending two different messages to the recipients, having different body content.  Although some mail clients out there might still support and execute Javascript without user intervention (I doubt it though), it could not be relied on at all.